# Menu does not behave as expected

Tags: android, android-menu

This is my menu xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_menu">

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"
    android:id="@+id/GooglePlayMenu"
    android:title="Title 1">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Sign_in_drawer"

            android:icon="@drawable/games_controller_grey"
            android:title="Sign in" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ach"
            android:icon="@drawable/games_achievements"
            android:title="Achievements" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"

    android:title="Title 2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/quizStart25"

            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"
            android:title="25 Questions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/quizStart10"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_airport_white_48dp"
            android:title="10 Questions" />
    </menu>
</item>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gallery"

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_library_white_48dp"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/stats"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_toc_white_48dp"
        android:title="Statistics" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/store"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_white_48dp"
        android:title="Store" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_48dp"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_white_48dp"
        android:title="About" />

</group>

<item android:title="Title 3">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/help_drawer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_white_48dp"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/report"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_report_problem_white_48dp"
            android:title="Contact Developer" />
        <item

            android:title="Google+ Community" />

    </menu>
</item>
```

and I have another menu that is similar but in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` I would like to decide which menu to show. Now to start with testing the menu above I have the following:

```
n = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav);
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d("NICK","onPrepareOptionsMenu");


   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, n.getMenu());
   //n.getMenu().add("Random item");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

and this will display my menu but *only* up to Title 3. Title 3 and its children items are *not* displayed as I expect them to be. Any when I uncomment the line `n.getMenu().add("Random item");` Title 3 and its children items are shown along with the "Random item". I'm wondering why does the menu behave like this? Is there something I am not doing properly?

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:id` to each element?

Comment: Yes and the result is the same. There was a copy-paste error, all items have an id in the code I am testing.

Comment: Does that include the ones like `Title 3`?

Comment: Yes, all items have a corresponding `android:id`

Answer (score 0):

return `false` in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` so its called all the time, if you have `onCreatOptionsMenu` and you do stuff there return `true` so its not called all the time

also for general purpose the menu here in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is the menu being passed to your `Activity` or `Fragment`; if you want to keep inflating menu all the time i suggest you do it in `onCreatOptionsMenu` and return `false` but you can rather do

```
menu = getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, n.getMenu());
```